# Laravel database error

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

Currently I'm making a ticket system with laravel. 
But I'm not quite familiar with the database structure.

I've made two tables with migrations.

Called:

Tickets, 
Comments

Obvisously a ticket can have multiple comments but a comment can only have one ticket. So it's a one to many relationship.

In the model of Tickets I've declared this:

```
class tickets extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'content', 'slug', 'status', 'user_id'];

    public function comments()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\comments', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

In the model of Comments I've declared this:

```
class comments extends Model
{
     protected $guarded = ['id'];
     public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\tickets');
    }
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
 public function show($slug)
  {
    $ticket = tickets::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
    $comments = $ticket->comments()->get;
    return view('tickets.show',compact('ticket','comments'));
  }
```

When exec this I receive the error:

> ErrorException in TicketsController.php line 77: Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$get

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're trying to access the `get` property when i think your purpose is to call the `get()` method. Replace this:

```
$comments = $ticket->comments()->get;
```

with

```
$comments = $ticket->comments()->get();
```

Comment: Woow nice! Seriously looked hours to this problem!! thanks!